# selenium.mouseOver() does not work with selenium server jar 2.25

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc

The `selenium.mouseOver(id)` function does not perform any action in selenium 2.25.
It works with selenium server 2.24.1 and the latest 2.28

I want to use selenium version 2.25 because of some reason.

Is it because of any bugs in 2.25?

Comment: You can see all the latest bugs and issues that are being resolved over at the [issue queue](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/list?can=2&q=mouseover). There are some reports of mouseover not working. Maybe you should explore / contributed to one of those reports.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do mouseover action using 2.25 jar perfectly in Firefox 12 , IE 8 & google chrome.